# Use MVC AccountController to login in Android App

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, authentication, controller

I'm working on a mobile application (in Android) which has to connect to an Azure database (this database is also used by the web version of the app). I succeeded to send POST/PUT/GET requests to the webservice API, using HttpURLConnection and now I'm trying to login in the app using the MVC AccountController. 
Here is the MVC AccountController method I'm trying to call:

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {   
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the LoginViewModel structure(first parameter of the Login method)

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

And here is what I've already tried, but I received: **Bad request**

```
public static String apiURL = "http://mysite/account/login";

public static String logIn() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(apiURL);
        JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
        postDataParams.put("Email", "test@yahoo.com");
        postDataParams.put("Password", "mypass");
        postDataParams.put("RememberMe", true);

        JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();
        finalJson.put("model", postDataParams);
        finalJson.put("returnUrl", "");

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(finalJson.toString());
        out.close();
        System.out.println(finalJson.toString());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("");
        int HttpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println("" + sb.toString());

        } else {
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: I tryed your code and hit my mvc action. (I also have android and ASP.NET MVC combination). and I get good status

Comment: @VladoPandžić Have you tried to log in from an android app/using java code with HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Yes. Using your code..but my mvc backend, although some situation..post method with email and password model

Comment: @VladoPandžić thank you for your time! Do you have any ideea of what should I check to see where the error comes from?

Comment: @VladoPandžić do you have special settings in web config or something like this? Can you show me your controller to see what's different from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came to a solution, someone told me that I should give up using the LoginViewModel which is also used by the web version of the app. So I wrote a new controller with a new Resource and it works:
Here is the Controller code:

```
public class AccountMobileController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly string _externalCookieScheme;

    // POST api/mobilelogin
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("/api/mobilelogin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginMobileResource model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Email == model.Email);
                /* _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                 return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);*/
                var modeltoreturn = new LoginMobileResource
                {
                    Status = "Ok",
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Password= "",
                    RememberMe = model.RememberMe,
                    UserId = user.Id
                };
                return Ok(modeltoreturn);
            }
            else
            {
                var modeltoreturn = new LoginMobileResource
                {
                    Status = "Wrong password",
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Password = "",
                    UserId = ""
                };
                return Ok(modeltoreturn);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        model.Status = "Non-existent account";
        return Ok(model);
    }
 }
```

And here is my LoginMobileResource

```
public class LoginMobileResource
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public String Status { get; set; }

    public String UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The java code is the same, except that now I send only the postDataParams

```
out.write(postDataParams.toString());
```